# Write two functions that will prompt for, read in, and verify that the user has entered numerical input

Tags: bash, input

I am new to bash scripting and I'm simply not sure what the issues are. The code looks fine to me so obviously there are a few things I don't understand. Also, I would like the "persistent_get_number" function to be able to return any number as this is going to be used for a basic cli calculator.

Here is the code:

```
is_numerical(){
  if [[ $user_input =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
 fi
}

persistent_get_number(){
  prompt="Enter a number:"
  user_input=""
  exit=0
  while [ $exit = 0 ]
  do
    echo $prompt
    read $user_input
    is_numerical $user_input
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]
    then
      exit=1
    else
      echo "Input must be numerical"
    fi
  done
  return $user_input
}

num1=$(persistent_get_number)
```

---

Updated code:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_numerical(){
  if [[ $user_input =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

persistent_get_number(){
  prompt="Enter a number:"
  user_input=""
  exit=0
  while [ $exit = 0 ]
  do
    echo "$prompt"
    read -r user_input
    is_numerical "$user_input"
    if ! [[ $? = 0 ]]
    then
      echo "Input must be numerical"
    else
      exit=1
    fi
  done
}

persistent_get_number
num1=$?
```

---

I am expecting the script to prompt the user to enter a number until the input is verified as numerical. Then, the number the user entered is returned by the "persistent_get_number" function and stored in "num1"

Comment: `return $user_input` should be `echo $user_input`.

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net, it has lots of warnings.

Comment: In the shell, exit status `0` is success, non-zero is failure.

Comment: You don't need to put your entire question into your title. Summarize.

Comment: That site is awesome, code is completely fixed now:

Comment: Trying to add the code below

Answer (score 0):

Some arrangement from your given script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_numerical(){
  if [[ $user_input =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
  then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

persistent_get_number(){
  exit=0
  prompt="Enter a number: "

  while [[ $exit == 0 ]]; do
    printf '%s' "$prompt" && read -r user_input
    is_numerical "$user_input"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "${user_input@A}"
      num1=$user_input && break
    else
      printf '%s\n' "${user_input@A}"
      echo "Input must be numerical"
    fi
  done
}

persistent_get_number
```

---

I would write it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

is_numerical(){
  [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && {
    return 0
  }
  return 1
}

persistent_get_number(){
  local prompt user_input
  prompt="Enter a number: "

  while read -rp "$prompt" user_input; do
    if is_numerical "$user_input"; then
      printf '%s\n' "${user_input@A}"
      num1=$user_input && break
    else
      printf '%s\n' "${user_input@A}"
      echo "Input must be numerical"
    fi
  done
}

persistent_get_number
```

---

- Remove the `&& break` if the intention is to continue the loop regardless of the value of `num1`
- See [Exit Status](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html)
- See `help return` and `help exit` from your shell.

Comment: All of these are great, thanks. Ill prolly keep it as is for now since it works after using shellcheck to edit it and because coming from more of a Python background the format just makes more since to me. I do how ever need to allow signed numbers like negative numbers and decimals in the user input as well and im not to good at regular expressions just yet. Any suggestions on how to add those to the expression?

Comment: @Daniel, bash does not have a native support for floating point numbers. see [Calculate floats in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022) some other shell does like the *ksh family.

Comment: Gotcha about the floating point numbers. Im using bc and adding a scale for division to fix that. Just need to be able to get what ever number the user wants to work with from the cli.

Comment: @Daniel, `bash` predates `python` so you might refrain from thinking `python` when writing `bash` code.

Comment: I understand but most languages have similarities and allow similar styles which is great

Comment: Also, I will check out all of the protocols for posting here on the stack and become more familiar them guys. Thank you